# Boost Fusion and Boost property_tree for de serialization of a structure

Tags: c++, json, serialization

I am trying to de-serialize a JSON data using boost::property_tree. I have set up a boost fusion sequence to identify the type of the structure member elements and use a function to de-serialize an appropriate JSON tree. It used to work fine for structures containing plain data types. When I try to apply the same action to a structure containing a structure, the logic fails and results in a compiler error . Could anyone see where I have gone wrong.

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/sequence.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_adt.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/is_sequence.hpp>

#include <boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp> 

#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

std::string type_name_to_recover = "";

template<typename type_t> 
struct is_container : public std::false_type {};

template<typename type_t, typename allocator_t> 
struct is_container < std::vector < type_t , allocator_t> > : public std::true_type {};

template<typename type_t, typename allocator_t> 
struct is_container < std::list < type_t , allocator_t> >  : public std::true_type {};

template <typename type_t> 
struct simple_serializer;


template <typename sequence_t, typename index_t> 
struct sequence_iterator
{
typedef typename boost::fusion::result_of::value_at<sequence_t, index_t>::type current_type_t;
typedef typename boost::mpl::next<index_t>::type next_index_t;
typedef boost::fusion::extension::struct_member_name<sequence_t, index_t::value> type_name_t;

static inline void read_json( boost::property_tree::ptree  &pt, sequence_t& sequence) 
{
    type_name_to_recover = type_name_t::call();
    simple_serializer<current_type_t>::read_json(pt, boost::fusion::at<index_t>(sequence));
    type_name_to_recover = "";
    sequence_iterator<sequence_t, next_index_t>::read_json(pt, sequence);
}

};


//tail of the sequence
template <typename sequence_t>
struct sequence_iterator<sequence_t, typename         boost::fusion::result_of::size<sequence_t>::type > 
{
static inline void read_json( boost::property_tree::ptree  &pt, sequence_t& sequence) { }
};

template < typename sequence_t >
struct sequence_iterator_final : sequence_iterator < sequence_t, boost::mpl::int_< 0 > > {};



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Plain old types serializer
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <typename type_t> 
struct serialize_pod
{
typedef serialize_pod<type_t> type;

static inline void read_json( boost::property_tree::ptree  &pt, type_t& t) 
{
    auto v = pt.get_child(type_name_to_recover);
    t =  boost::lexical_cast<type_t>(v.data());
}
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Sequence serializer
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template <typename sequence_t> 
struct serialize_sequence 
{
typedef serialize_sequence<sequence_t> type;

static inline void read_json( boost::property_tree::ptree  &pt, sequence_t& sequence) 
{
    sequence_iterator_final<sequence_t>::read_json(pt, sequence);
}

};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Container serializer
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <typename container_type_t> 
struct serialize_container 
{
typedef serialize_container<container_type_t> type;

template <typename type_t>
static void read_json( boost::property_tree::ptree  &pt, std::vector<type_t> &t) 
{
    std::string temp_name = type_name_to_recover;
    type_name_to_recover = "";
    BOOST_FOREACH( boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type &tree_node_value, pt.get_child(temp_name) )
    {
        boost::property_tree::ptree subtree = (boost::property_tree::ptree) tree_node_value.second ;
        if( subtree.empty() )
        {
            auto tree_node_y = subtree.data();
            type_t type_val;
            simple_serializer<type_t>::read_json(tree_node_y, type_val);
            t.push_back(type_val);
        }
        else
        {
            auto tree_node_x = subtree.data();
            type_t type_val;
            simple_serializer<type_t>::read_json(tree_node_x, type_val);
            t.push_back(type_val);
        }
    }
}

};


template <typename type_t> 
struct resolve_serializer_type 
{
  typedef 
typename boost::mpl::eval_if< boost::fusion::traits::is_sequence < type_t > , serialize_sequence < type_t > , 
typename boost::mpl::eval_if< is_container < type_t > , boost::mpl::identity < serialize_container < type_t > >,
serialize_pod < type_t >  >  > 
  ::type type;
};

//
template <typename type_t> 
struct simple_serializer : public resolve_serializer_type<type_t>::type { };




struct StructB
{
int s;
std::vector<int> vi_b; 
};

struct StructA
{ 
int v;  
std::vector<int> vi; 
std::vector<StructB> lb;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT( StructB, (int , s) (std::vector<int>, vi_b) )
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT( StructA, (int, v) (std::vector<int>, vi) (std::vector<StructB>, lb ) )


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

StructA sa_in;

std::string json_data = "{\"v\":20,\"vi\":[123,456,123],\"lb\":[{\"s\":999,\"vi_b\":[909,808]},{\"s\":888,\"vi_b\":[707]},{\"s\":777,\"vi_b\":[606,505,404,303]}]}";

std::stringstream is(json_data);
boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json(is, pt);

simple_serializer<StructA>::read_json( pt , sa_in);
}
```

Error message:
    1>e:\fusiongarage\apr_25\source.cpp(122): error C2664:   'serialize_sequence::read_json' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'boost::property_tree::ptree &'
    1>          with
    1>          [
    1>              sequence_t=StructB
    1>          ]
    1>          and
    1>          [
    1>              _Elem=char,
    1>              _Traits=std::char_traits,
    1>              _Ax=std::allocator
    1>          ]
    1>          e:\fusiongarage\apr_25\source.cpp(46) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void serialize_container::read_json(boost::property_tree::ptree &,std::vector<_Ty> &)' being compiled
    1>          with
    1>          [
    1>              container_type_t=std::vector,
    1>              _Ty=StructB
    1>          ]
    1>          e:\fusiongarage\apr_25\source.cpp(44) : while compiling class template member function 'void sequence_iterator::read_json(boost::property_tree::ptree &,sequence_t &)'
    1>          with
    1>          [
    1>              sequence_t=StructA,
    1>              index_t=boost::mpl::int_<2>
    1>          ]
    1>          e:\fusiongarage\apr_25\source.cpp(48) : see reference to class template instantiation 'sequence_iterator' being compiled
    1>          with
    1>          [
    1>              sequence_t=StructA,
    1>              index_t=boost::mpl::int_<2>
    1>          ]
    1>
    1>Build FAILED.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the read_json function requires a sub-tree to be passed in for structures that contain other structures. Changing the container serializer as below seems to solve the problem. Could anyone confirm that the solution is valid.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Container serializer
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <typename container_type_t> 
struct serialize_container 
{
typedef serialize_container<container_type_t> type;

template <typename type_t>
static void read_json( boost::property_tree::ptree  &pt, std::vector<type_t> &t) 
{
    std::string temp_name = type_name_to_recover;
    type_name_to_recover = "";
    BOOST_FOREACH( boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type &tree_node_value, pt.get_child(temp_name) )
    {
        boost::property_tree::ptree subtree = (boost::property_tree::ptree) tree_node_value.second ;
        if( subtree.empty() )
        {
            type_t type_val;
            simple_serializer<type_t>::read_json(subtree, type_val);
            t.push_back(type_val);
        }
        else
        {
            type_t type_val;

            std::stringstream os;
            boost::property_tree::write_json(os, subtree);

            boost::property_tree::ptree pt_x;
            boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json(os, pt_x);

            simple_serializer<type_t>::read_json(pt_x, type_val);

            t.push_back(type_val);
        }
    }
}

};
```